# Removing All Text From a Column

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, data-science, data-analysis

I am trying to teach myself Python for data analysis, and I am working with a dataset that contains both strings and integers.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxYOe.png)

I was able to fix the reviews_avg column by using :

df['reviews_avg_num'] = df['reviews_avg'].str[8:11]

That took out all text and left me with just numbers.

However, when I get to the reviews_count, it ranges from single digits all the way up to hundreds of thousands.

Is there a way I can simply remove all text and just leave the numbers?

Thank you for any help with this.

Answer (score 2):

this code will remove all string gives you remaining digits, including the . (modified as per alex)

```
df[column] = df[column].apply(lambda x: (''.join(c for c in x if (c.isdigit() or c =='.')))
```

Comment: Careful: this turns "4.6 out of 5" into "465".

Comment: Thanks Alex!. added or condition to tackle it

Comment: Careful: this turns "4.6 out of 5" into "4.65".